# Bars not showing when saving Bar Chart view

Tags: swift, uiview, ios-charts

My chart shows up fine in my app, but when I save the `chartView` to camera roll or for use in another `UIViewController` the **bars don't show up**.

Fine in my app:

[image]

Bars don't show up when save the `chartView` to camera roll or for use in another `UIViewController`:

[image]

I've tried a few ways of doing this -specifically for saving the `chartView` to Camera Roll- like:

1)

```
    let image1 = chartView.getChartImage(transparent: false)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image1!, nil, nil, nil)
```

[image]

2)

```
    let image2 = captureScreen()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image2!, nil, nil, nil)
```

[image]

3)

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init(view: UIView) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.init(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
    }
}

    let image3 = UIImage(view: chartView)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image3, nil, nil, nil)
```

[image]

But nothing works for me. Any ideas why?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when capturing image using getChartImage. So I made my own function for capturing Image.

Basically I make a UIView class and inherited LineChartView.
Made UIView extension for taking snapShot of my chartView.

Implement this function in UIView extension:

```
func snapShot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size , false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
```

And call it like this

```
let image = chartView.snapShot()
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Glad to know someone else was having trouble with the same thing and figured it out.  I think I understand that you put the `snapshot()` function inside of `extension UIView {...}`, but wondering what is in the UIView class and inherited LineChartView"?

Comment: I did not make ViewController and inherit LineChartView. rather then I made a class and inherited LineChartView. So the chart is a view for me. so thats why I made UIView extension. Is it clear?

Comment: Ah, got it!  Makes sense.  Thanks I got this all working now!